# How to update a large table from AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, html-table

How can I update every cell of the following large table (10 rows X 30 columns) using AJAX?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>puts @table[0][0]</td>
    <td>puts @table[0][1]</td>
    ... 27 columns go here
    <td>puts @table[0][29]</td>
  </tr>
  ... 8 rows go here
  <tr>
    <td>puts @table[9][0]</td>
    <td>puts @table[9][1]</td>
    ... 27 columns go here
    <td>puts @table[9][29]</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I was able to update the cell at row 0 and column 0 by giving it a specific id, as follows

```
    <td id="r0c0">puts @table[0][0]</td>
```

and using the following javascript, which is working fine

```
document.getElementById("r0c0").innerHTML = '<%= @new_r0c0_value %>'
```

but since the table is very large (300 cells) I'm looking for an idea how to update the 300 cells from an array of values without identifying each table's cell with a specific id.

Anyone has a smart idea how to pass an array in the AJAX response and how to update this large table using that AJAX response?

Comment: Could you build the complete markup for the table and send that back to the client? Then you would remove the existing table and just drop the "<table>...</table>" string sent from the server into the page. Don't know Rails but I've done this in JSP. Otherwise you could use a datatable plugin (like YUI DataTable), which often support ajax loading and update.

Comment: are you sure you are getting response from ajax ?? if so how are you getting rails variables ??

Comment: @dku.rajkumar : yes, I'm sure about that ; for example, "@new_r0c0_value" is calculated inside a controller method I called "update_values" and it works fine for all other fields in the same form

Comment: @Tony R : Thanks for the prompt response ; this looks like a good idea and I'll explore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put an id on the table tag itself, you can get all cells in the table into an array like this:

```
document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('td');
```

You will then have an array of all the `td` elements in the table which you can loop through and update.

In some browsers, it may perform better to just remove the entire table and construct a new one with the new data in it rather than individually changing all the cells.  The issue is that since tables can have dynamic layout, the browser may not be very efficient about relaying out the table each time you change a cell.

Comment: Why not loop through each row instead?

Comment: @AlxVallejo - I don't understand your question.  The OP asked how to update all cells in the table and this answer suggests how to get a list of all the cells so one can loop through them.  There are a whole bunch of other ways to do it to, but this is simple and works.

Comment: Ah, you're right. This was tl;dr. I would imagine in most cases you would be calling from a database such that it would be easier to loop through a row of attributes rather than all cells at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

If you can construct an array like this
[[1,2,..27],[1,2,..27],..[1,2,..27]]

then it is easy to load the data into that table without using ID or anything else.

```
<table>
        <% arr.each do |inner_arr| %>
                <tr>
                <% inner_arr.each do |val| %>
                        <td><%= val %></td>
                <% end %>
                </tr>
        <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Vadivelan. What I'm missing is the js piece that updates the table from AJAX response, not how to build it the 1st time on the server.

Comment: Yeah you can still achieve this in js. Place above mentioned table content in a partial file. In you ajax action, construct array and use `code`page.replace_html 'elementID', :partial => file_name`code`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [:nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector if using JQuery. I am doing it this way to highlight the currently updated record in the table listing with Ajax.

I have @assets which is the collection of all the objects, and @asset is the current record which is updated. The **_assets.html.erb** partial with the table looks like this:

```
<% @assets.each_with_index do |asset, index| %>
  <tr class="link">
    <td class="num"> <%= link_to index + 1, asset, :remote => true, :onclick => "$('#spinner').show()" %> </td>
    <td> 
      <%= link_to asset.try(:patient).try(:display_name), asset, :remote => true, 
        :onclick => "$('#spinner').show()" %> 
    </td>
    ...
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

and do this in **update.js.erb**:

```
...
$("#assets").html("<%= escape_javascript( render "assets" ) %>");

$("table.listing > tbody tr:nth-child(<%= @assets.index(@asset) + 1 %>)").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
...
```

Selecting the nth-child with the index and highlight.